How to Process Kinesis Video Stream GetMedia API output to S3 as wav file using python?
The question is related to one old post
How to decode AWS Kinesis Video Stream GetMedia API output to mp3/wav?
I am trying voice mail system in AWS connect. If an agent is not available to handle the customer's call, the customer should record his/her message. Once agent is available, the agent will playback the message.
From AWS connect, the customer's recording(voice mail) is storing into AWS Kinesis Video Stream(KVS). But from KVS, i am not able to extract the audio file & push that into S3 as wav file. I am trying this using python. Did we get the solution using python or still we need to use Java only to extract audio file from Kinesis video stream? Anyone, please answer.
Output of payload [Sample only]:
\x0b\xbc\n\x9c\x06\x9c\x03\xb4\x00\xb4\xfc\x94\xfc\x14\xfeX\x00x\x00\xac\x01\x10\x00T\xfe\x1c\xff|\xffL\xff\xf4\xfc\xa4\xfa\xc4\xf5D\xf5\xc4\xf4D\xf6\xa4\xf8d\xfc\x9c\xfeH\x00,\x02\xcc\x02\x9c\x03\x1c\x04\x12T\xc3g\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Uss\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Kg\xc8\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00AE\xa3\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\tContactIdD\x87\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00$dd3be7ac-f61a-49a6-9683-484175767604\x12T\xc3g\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Vss\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Lg\xc8\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00BE\xa3\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\nInstanceIdD\x87\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\audio/L16;rate=8000;channels=1;\x12T\xc3g\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00:ss\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000g\xc8\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00&E\xa3\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11AUDIO_TO_CUSTOMERD\x87\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x012\x12T\xc3g\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00<ss\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x002g\xc8\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(E\xa3\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13AUDIO_FROM_CUSTOMERD\x87\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x011\x12T\xc3g\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000ss\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00&g\xc8\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1cE\xa3\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06EventsD\x87\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02[]\x12T\xc3g\x10\x00\x00\xa5ss\x10\x00\x00\x9fg\xc8\x10\x00\x005E\xa3\x10\x00\x00"
By using python, i tried to exact the audio file. But i couldn't
